# WCF channelfactory with settings from the config file?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a server&client solution that are using WCF. The client will ask a service about the URL to an active server at runtime and to be able to set this I use ChannelFactory. I however still needs to use all other WCF settings from the config file. This is how I do it :

```
var clientSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;

            var address = string.Empty;
            for(int i = 0; i < clientSection.Endpoints.Count; i++)
            {
                if(clientSection.Endpoints[i].Name == endpointConfigurationName)
                {
                    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(clientSection.Endpoints[i].Address.ToString());
                    var netHttpBinding = new NetHttpBinding(clientSection.Endpoints[i].BindingConfiguration);
                    var serviceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(T)), netHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

                    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(serviceEndpoint);

                    break;
                }
            }
```

The problem is that I got 2 BehaviorExtensions that are used by some of the endpoints like this.

```
<services>
<endpoint binding="netHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="protoEndpointBehavior" address="BinaryHttpProto" bindingNamespace="http://MyApp.ServiceContracts/2007/11" contract="MyApp.ServiceContracts.IMyAppClientService" />
</services>

<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="protoEndpointBehavior">
          <protobuf />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

<extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.668, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
```

The question is how I read this from the clientSection.Endpoints? and sets it on the channelFactory? I know that I could create then manually like this :

```
serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ProtoEndpointBehavior());
            serviceEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomMessageInspectorBehavior());
```

But then this will be a hard coded static and it will apply to all endpoints, I need to be able to change it from the config.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hade to create everything in code, a mixed solution was no good, not in my case where I use alot of custom stuff.

Comment: Congratulations. But still, your answer is usefull only with som example and explanation..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the ChannelFactory by yourself. Just create a ClientService class that inherits from `ClientBase<T>`. The constructor of the `ClientBase<T>` accepts a EndpointName and adds automatically the behavior that is associated with this Endpoint. The `ClientBase<T>` also give you the possibility to access the `ChannelFactory<T>` and you can open as much channel as you want. the only thing that you need further to do, is to add a name for each EndPoint in the config that you want to use.

```
<endpoint binding="..." name="MyEndPoint" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like I need to add code for each service method in this ClientBase class? Like this : return base.Channel.MySimpleMethod(request); Is this true? I got hundreds of webmethods.

Comment: Yes, this is the downside and the normal way. We worked around that with only 2 methods. Our WebService has 2 methods, one for Requests with results and one without result. All the other stuff is handled through the request, we just look at the given RequestType and invoke the handlers that can work with the requests.

Comment: Sorry, do not really understad? How could hundreds of webmethods be only 2? All need there own methodname, request and response?

Comment: Your method has only to accept a Request, then you inherit from this Request like `CustomerSearchRequest` with the properties you like to use with your search. Then you need some kind of base handler, that checks the type of the request and invokes a handler that can handle it, something like `CustomerSearchRequestHandler` and the handler results the response. If you want, you can make the SearchRequest generic that you dont need to make an SearchRequest for each type you want to search for.